# An alternative to BEGIN;COMMIT; since the transaction affects my ability to use LAST_INSERT_ID()?

Tags: mysql, database

I need to INSERT INTO multiple tables per entry, and to do this safely I decided to make the entire statement a TRANSACTION. However, my code relies on LAST_INSERT_ID() being updated with each INSERT INTO, and it seems like LAST_INSERT_ID() is only updated **each TRANSACTION**. Therefore, I either need an alternative to the typical START TRANSACTION;COMMIT; format, or I need an alternative to LAST_INSERT_ID() that will still achieve the same goal.

Both **person** and **yearandpage** have primary keys that are auto-incremented, and those keys are foreign keys in the table **personinschoolyearbook**.

The original problem that has led me to ask this question is that I have two tables with primary keys and a relational table that references both. How can I update all three at the same time with one data entry? I have looked into *cascading referential integrity* which would make my foreign keys automatically update, but I do not think this would work since my relational table has a non-foreign key value (status) that must be manually inserted.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO person (firstname, middlename, lastname, maidenname)
VALUES ('Test2fname', NULL, 'Test2lname', NULL);
INSERT INTO personinschoolyearbook (personid, yearandpageid, status)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 0, 'Test2status'); --The zero is a placeholder, to be replaced with the primary key id that will be created in the next INSERT INTO
SELECT @personid := LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO yearandpage (yearincluded, page, schoolid, url) --Here is where the LAST_INSERT_ID() should update but doesn't
VALUES (0000, 00, 2, 'Test2url');
UPDATE personinschoolyearbook SET yearandpageid=LAST_INSERT_ID()
WHERE personinschoolyearbook.personid = @personid;
COMMIT;
```

Right now, the value of LAST_INSERT_ID() does not change and in my relational table **personinschoolyearbook** the column that should have the new id that was taken from **yearandpage** is instead the same id as the one taken from **person**.

Comment: Have you confirmed the preceding yearandpage insert succeeds?

Comment: Yes, it works fine.

Comment: Are you suggesting that LAST_INSERT_ID() should have updated, which means it's not tied to transactions? Because I don't know for sure which is the case.

Answer (score 1):

LAST_INSERT_ID() always reports the most recent auto-inc value generated in the current session. This is not limited by transactions. You can start a new transaction and LAST_INSERT_ID() will still return the most recent auto-inc value.

```
mysql> create table foo (id serial primary key);

mysql> begin;

mysql> insert into foo () values ();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select last_insert_id() into @id1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into foo () values ();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select last_insert_id() into @id2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @id1, @id2;
+------+------+
| @id1 | @id2 |
+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |
+------+------+
```

If you insert a value into a table that does have an auto-inc, but you specify a nonzero value and therefore prevent the auto-inc from generating a new id, it also does not change the value returned by LAST_INSERT_ID();

```
mysql> insert into foo set id = 10;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from foo;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
| 10 |
+----+

mysql> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|                3 |
+------------------+
```

If you have a primary key that is *not* an auto-inc, an INSERT does not change the value returned by LAST_INSERT_ID() for the most recent id generated in the current session by any auto-inc, even if that was for another table, or in another transaction.

```
mysql> create table bar (id bigint primary key); -- not AUTO_INCREMENT

mysql> insert into bar set id = 42;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|                3 |
+------------------+
```

Comment: This is good to know, thank you. That means the problem isn't with LAST_INSERT_ID(), it's something else. I will keep troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in Bill Karwin's answer, LAST_INSERT_ID() is not affected by transactions. The reason it was not updating was because when I went to INSERT INTO **yearandpage**, if the entry already existed, then no data would be entered and as such there would be no value for LAST_INSERT_ID() to take. Uueerdo brought up how this may be the problem, but since I had somehow missed the duplicate entry error when running the code, I thought the INSERT INTO was working fine.

Duplicate entries were the cause of my problem and needed to be accounted for in the project, so to get around this issue, I used ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), which you can read more about at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

This is my final code:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO person (firstname, middlename, lastname, maidenname)
VALUES ('Test2fname', NULL, 'Test2lname', NULL);
INSERT INTO personinschoolyearbook (personid, yearandpageid, status)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 0, 'Test2status');
SELECT @personid := LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO yearandpage (yearincluded, page, schoolid, url)
VALUES (0000, 00, 2, 'Test2url') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE yearandpageid = LAST_INSERT_ID(yearandpageid);
UPDATE personinschoolyearbook SET yearandpageid=LAST_INSERT_ID()
WHERE personinschoolyearbook.personid = @personid;
COMMIT;
```